# MPV plays no audio when watching a video

Tags: sound, mpv-media-player

I installed [mpv](https://mpv.io/) with vapoursynth support in order to use SVP for Linux (program to watch videos in 60fps) but when I play a video file there is no audio at all. Volume Control also shows no signs of any audio output.

Other video players work fine but do not work with SVP for some reason so I'm stuck with mvp for now.

My config file looks like this as instructed [here](https://www.svp-team.com/wiki/SVP:Linux#mpv_configuration):

```
hwdec=audo-copy 
input-ipc-server=/tmp/mpvsocket
```

What are my possibilities now? I'm fairly new to Linux

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it using these additional ffmpeg configs

```
//dependencies
sudo apt-get install libx264-dev libmp3lame-dev libfdk-aac-dev

// type these commands in the folder where you build mpv
echo --enable-libx264 >> ffmpeg_options
echo --enable-libmp3lame >> ffmpeg_options
echo --enable-libfdk-aac >> ffmpeg_options
echo --enable-nonfree >> ffmpeg_options
```

Answer (score 0):

Please forgive me for reverting to basics, but this is what often happens to cause an audio failure.

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>LeftClick</kbd> shows all available sound tracks for a file in mpv. Make sure the sound track you need is selected.

<kbd>LeftClick</kbd> by itself toggles mute off and on; make sure it's off.

The mouse wheel dials volume up and down; please dial it up.

Here's a [list of those controls](https://mpv.io/manual/stable/#the-interface) and more.

Also, please try videos you know which do have sound tracks, as verified with another app.

Comment: Didn't help unfortunately. I think it has to do with building mpv myself since when I use the version installed via apt the sound works. However that version does not have vapoursynth support which I need.